# Excel Macro To Copy Image From Network Drive To Other Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA coding and am trying to help out a friend who is trying to have a macro that will download/copy multiple images from a network drive, rename them and save them to a folder on the desktop.

The data in the spreadsheet is set up as such. 
The macro would copy the image from the paths listed in column B and then rename the image with data from column A and save it to a folder on the Desktop

```
column A  -         column B      -              column C

3487458   -  N:/path1/image1.jpg  -  http://www.website.com/data.pdf

5412132   -  N:/path2/image2.jpg  -  http://www.website.com/data2.pdf
```

I have this that works for the Data in column C that are html links, but I need it to work for the data in column B that are paths to a network drive.

```
Const TargetFolder = "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Output\"
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
(ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Sub Test()
   For Each Hyperlink In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
       LocalFileName = ActiveSheet.Cells(Hyperlink.Range.Row, 1).Value & 
".pdf"
   Call HTTPDownloadFile(Hyperlink.Address, TargetFolder & LocalFileName)
   Next Hyperlink
End Sub
```

Thanks, Roy

EDIT: CODE THAT WORKED

```
Sub copythem()
Dim rw As Long, start_row As Long, end_row As Long
Dim destination_folder As String
Dim suffix As String

suffix = ".jpg"

With ActiveSheet
    start_row = 1
    end_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    destination_folder = "C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Output\" ' Set destination as user's desktop

    For rw = start_row To end_row
        If Dir(.Cells(rw, 2)) <> "(.Cells(rw, 2))" Then
            FileCopy .Cells(rw, 2), destination_folder & .Cells(rw, 1) & suffix
        Else
            MsgBox "File: " & .Cells(rw, 2) & " is not found."
        End If
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Check out [this site](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm). It's just one or two lines of code to move/copy a file in VBA.

Comment: I've changed your references from VBS to VBA as you're using spreadsheets (VBS is a different language).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a lot to go on, but making a few assumptions on the way, like the filetype (`suffix`) and when you say 'desktop' - you mean the desktop on a recent version of Windows..

```
Sub copythem()
    Dim rw As Long, start_row As Long, end_row As Long
    Dim destination_folder As String
    Dim suffix As String

    suffix = ".jpg"

    With ActiveSheet
        start_row = 1
        end_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        destination_folder = Environ("homedrive") & Environ("homepath") & "\desktop\output\" ' Set destination as output folder in user's desktop

        For rw = start_row To end_row
            If Dir(.Cells(rw, 2)) <> "" Then
                FileCopy .Cells(rw, 2), destination_folder & .Cells(rw, 1) & suffix
            Else
                MsgBox "File: " & .Cells(rw, 2) & " is not found."
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you decide to point the destination_folder to something else, make sure the folder exists before you run this.

Comment: I keep getting a path not found error with the debug pointing at FileCopy .Cells(rw, 2), destination_folder & .Cells(rw, 1) & suffix

Comment: suffix changed to .jpg
 destination_folder = "C:\Users\rykenes\Desktop\Output\" ' Set destination as user's desktop
Is the only thing I edited

Comment: After some tweaking and reading, I got it working exactly as needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great news! If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark it answered. If you want me to change anything before you mark it, let me know.